# number of items on a listview Depending on the device screen

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to get number of items that are visible on the device screen .

for example :

I want to get 5 :

[image]

I want to get 6 :

[image]

Comment: Post what have you tried!

Comment: number of items that are visible on device screen ! it is may be differen for sw240,sw320 ...

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use listview's [getLastVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition())

> Returns the position within the adapter's data set for the last item
>   displayed on screen.

and [getFirstVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition())

> Returns the position within the adapter's data set for the first item
>   displayed on screen.

as

```
int visibleChildCount = (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
```